# Why my addEventListener not working with my laravel blade file

Tags: javascript, laravel

Does anyone here knows what is wrong my js code? been doing this kind of code when my button on my blade file is just one and is being inside a @foreach.

I'm getting no errors hence hard to debug..

```
let Btn_showProfiles = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-show-profiles");

Btn_showProfiles.forEach(function(Btn_showProfile){
     Btn_showProfile.addEventListener('click', btn_show=>{

     console.log("test");

       });
 })
```

My code inside blade file..

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-7 mt-3 mb-2">
            @foreach($profiles as $profile)
            <div class="mb-2">
                    <h3>{{ $profile->name }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ $profile->age }}</p>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn-show-profiles" data target="#user_profile"</a> 
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Thank you! :D

Comment: what's there in Btn_showProfiles? And `data-target` attribute mentioned as `data target`  in your code.

Comment: it's probably not related to blade, you should provide more complete example.

Comment: my eventlistener is not working with my anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Array.from(Btn_showProfiles).forEach(profile => {
    profile.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log('works');
    });
});
```

Shortest solution

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-show-profiles')
  .forEach(element => input.addEventListener('click', event => {
   console.log(element);
}));
```